# Node.js Azure WebJob: How to deploy from Visual Studio Team Services with Continuous Delivery

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

We have an existing Web App in Azure that we are deploying a Node.js webjob to.

We are currently deploying the webjob during the build (CI) process by copying the run.js and node_modules folder into the web app's app_data/jobs/continuous  directory as per the only tutorial I found, then building and deploying the WebApp itself using CD.

While this works, it seems a little hacky, and it takes a really long time to deploy the web app now due to the huge number of files in the node_modules directory.

Is there a more automated approach, i.e. deploying the node.js webjob to an existing web app?  I can find all kinds of tutorials for this scenario re: asp.net projects but only the one for node.js webjobs, which is described in para 2 above)

**Update**

I am using the instructions in Amit's blog:  http://blog.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/#.VyC06DArKHs

Comment: Are both your WebApp files and WebJobs files in the same repository?

Comment: Yes they are, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you are using Git to deploy your ASP.NET application to Azure Web Apps service, you can leverage npm manage file `package.json` to install the node modules via deployment task.

You can try the following steps:

1. Add a `package.json` file in your root directory path with the content including your needed dependencies. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies.
2. If you have the project in Visual Studio, you can right click the `wwwroot`, then click `Add` => "New item", then under the `Client-side` tab, select the `NPM Configuration File` to add.
   [image] 
   [image]
   After creating and config the npm configuration file, the Azure deployment task will install the dependencies automatically.
3. Create the webjob script and folder in your root directory in your repo or project. E.G. `app_data\jobs\continuous\testwebjob\run.js`. You can directly `require` the module, it will find the module in the `node_modules` in root directory.

Afterall, your root directory of your project will have the similar structure:
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Unfortunately, we are not using Asp.NET5 (which based on your use of wwwroot I assume you are in this case) and we won't until the .NET Core team gets that project in a much more stable condition as much as I like it.  If you are not talking about Asp.NET5 then how is the wwwroot concept used in traditional Asp.NET?

Comment: We are using npm in our CI process already and then copying the process over into the webapp before building and publishing using a series of tasks in the VSO build definition.  We then use the VSO Release mechanism afterwards to deploy the site.  The release portion of the CD process is what is taking longer than would be expected.  I am updating my question with a link to the blog I used to set this up.